# Coloring Wpf DataGrid Cell Border

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="Button1" Height="25" Width="100" Content="Fill Data" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Button x:Name="Button2" Height="25" Width="100" Content="Color Border" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,30,0,0"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1" Width="500" Height="100" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

vb.net

```
Class MainWindow

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim DataSet1 As System.Data.DataSet = New System.Data.DataSet
    Dim DataTable1 As System.Data.DataTable = New System.Data.DataTable
    DataTable1.Columns.Add("Name")
    DataTable1.Columns.Add("Sur Name")
    DataTable1.Columns.Add("Country")
    DataTable1.Columns.Add("Gender")
    DataTable1.Rows.Add({"Donald", "Trump", "United States", "Male"})
    DataTable1.Rows.Add({"Angela", "Merkel", "Germany", "Female"})
    DataTable1.Rows.Add({"Theresa", "May", "England", "Female"})
    DataTable1.Rows.Add({"Emmanuel", "Macron", "France", "Male"})
    DataTable1.Rows.Add({"Vladimir", "Putin", "Russia", "Male"})
    DataTable1.Rows.Add({"Recep Tayyip", "Erdogan", "Turkey", "Male"})
    DataTable1.Rows.Add({"Justin", "Trudeau", "Canada", "Male"})
    DataTable1.Rows.Add({"Xi", "Jinping", "China", "Male"})
    DataTable1.Rows.Add({"Mahmoud", "Abbas", "Palestine", "Male"})
    DataTable1.Rows.Add({"Moon", "Jae-in", "South Korea", "Male"})
    DataTable1.Rows.Add({"Shinzō", "Abe", "Japan", "Male"})
    DataTable1.Rows.Add({"Nicolas", "Maduro", "Venezuela", "Male"})
    DataTable1.Rows.Add({"Sergio", "Mattarella", "Italy", "Male"})
    DataTable1.Rows.Add({"Kim", "Jong-un", "North Korea", "Male"})
    DataSet1.Tables.Add(DataTable1)
    DataGrid1.ItemsSource = DataSet1.Tables(0).DefaultView
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim myDataGridRow As DataGridRow = CType(DataGrid1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(DataGrid1.Items(1)), DataGridRow)
    Dim myDataGridCell As DataGridCell = CType(DataGrid1.Columns(2).GetCellContent(myDataGridRow).Parent, DataGridCell)
    myDataGridCell.BorderBrush = New SolidColorBrush(CType(ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#ff0000"), Color))
End Sub

End Class
```

Please run the above codes and click Button1 and Button2.

Scroll down on DataGrid and see that Germany, China and North Korea border colors are red.

Normally only Germany border must be red.

So, why three cell borders are red instead of one?

***Note:*** I need **code behind solution** not xaml solution.

Comment: You're using WPF in a "wrong way" - as you would do in WinForms. To change data grid cell's border color in WPF, use data grid cell `Style`s and `DataTrigger`s.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23325478/wpf-datagrid-customization-border-cell-corners-etc) you can get some idea how to do that in XAML.

Comment: @dymanoid I need code behind solution not xaml. But thanks anyway.